# How install Start Angular template correctly?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, templates, ubuntu

I'm new in the Angular development, so I found [this template](http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/) and I would like to use it. So I'm doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y npm
sudo npm install -g bower
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Clone the repository of the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/start-angular/sb-admin-angular.git
cd sb-admin-agular
npm install bower
```

But when I try to execute the command `npm start`, it gives me the follow error:

```
vagrant@TheMachine:~/sb-admin-angular$ npm start

> sb-admin@0.0.0 start /home/vagrant/sb-admin-angular
> grunt serve

/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
vagrant@TheMachine:~/sb-admin-angular$
```

Any idea how to solve that ? Or what is causing it ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some dependencies. Looks like you only installed bower. Try installing all dependencies using
`npm install`

Re-follow the installation instructions on the Github page from 5-7:

> 5. npm install - bower install is ran from the postinstall
> 6. npm start - a shortcut for grunt serve
> 7. npm run dist - a shortcut for grunt serve:dist to minify the files for deployment

Comment: @ValterHenrique What if you try running it as Administrator or root: According to the log: npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Some installation routines requires to find the binary "node".
But on Debian based systems the binary is named "nodejs".
To get around this problem I created a syslink.
But be aware that this may introduce other problems later.

Comment: I think you mean symlink. Also if it's an debian derivative like ubuntu, there are legacy packages, like this one https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/nodejs-legacy which doesn't require you to mess around in the system yourself.